# How to change the username for uv4l on raspberry pi?

Tags: raspbian, uv4l

I am using `uv4l` on raspberry pi. I can't seem to find the username option in the config file `/etc/uv4l/uv4l-raspicam.conf`. The only usernames available are `'user'` and `'admin'`. I can change the passwords alright but how do I change the username?

Edit:
I am trying to change the username login specific to uv4l program on raspberry pi. This is the username I enter on basic auth prompt on browser when I open webserver for uv4l